# Get data from DataTable to class with list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to get data from a DataTable in order to populate an object like:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int IdStudent { get; set; }
}

public class ClassRoomModel
{
    public List<StudentModel> Students { get; set; } = new List<StudentModel>();
    public int IdClassRoom { get; set; }
    public string ClassRoom { get; set; }
}
```

My DataTable return these data:

| ClassRoom | IdClassRoom | IdStudent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1001 |
| A | 1 | 1002 |
| A | 1 | 1003 |
| B | 2 | 2001 |
| B | 2 | 2002 |
| B | 2 | 2003 |

How can I distinct or group by ClassRoom with relative Students?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you getting the `DataTable`? If you're getting it from an SQL query, do you need the `DataTable` at all?

Comment: Yes, I get DataTable from SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<ClassRoomModel> classes = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => (ClassRoom:r.Field<string>("ClassRoom"),IdClassRoom:r.Field<int>("IdClassRoom")))
    .Select(g => new ClassRoomModel
    {
        ClassRoom = g.Key.ClassRoom,
        IdClassRoom = g.Key.IdClassRoom,
        Students = g.Select(r => new StudentModel{ IdStudent = r.Field<int>("IdStudent") }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

because Jochem asked in a comment how to do it with the resultSelector argument in `GroupBy`:

```
List<ClassRoomModel> classes = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(
        r => (ClassRoom: r.Field<string>("ClassRoom"), IdClassRoom: r.Field<int>("IdClassRoom")), 
        r => new StudentModel { IdStudent = r.Field<int>("IdStudent")}
    )
    .Select(studentsGroup => new ClassRoomModel
    {
        ClassRoom = studentsGroup.Key.ClassRoom,
        IdClassRoom = studentsGroup.Key.IdClassRoom,
        Students = studentsGroup.ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Personally i prefer the first version.

Comment: Ok it works, but I had to modify groub by like: .GroupBy(r => new { ClassRoom = r.Field<string>("ClassRoom"),IdClassRoom = r.Field<int>("IdClassRoom") })

Comment: @R1g3L: You dont use a current .NET framework? The ValueTuples exist since C#7

Comment: Yes sorry, maybe because I used .NET 4.5

Comment: @R1g3L: then you should download the System.ValueTuple from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/ But yes, you can also use anonymous types. They just have little overhead compared to the tuples

Comment: Might be a bit off topic but is there any difference between using select to map the grouped data and the 3th parameter of the group by function? [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__), result selector

Comment: @JochemVanHespen: feel free to ask a question, i don't think it exists. I prefer using `Select` most times since the code is more readable imo. You also don't have a `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` in the resultSelector, so you can't chose from the group but only from the grouped element. Here i could not create the list of students with the resultSelector because i dont have the group there. I have edited my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ClassRoom", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("IdClassRoom", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("IdStudent", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", 1, 1001});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", 1, 1002});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", 1, 1003});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B", 2, 2001});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B", 2, 2002});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B", 2, 2003});

            List<ClassRoomModel> rooms = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("IdClassRoom"))
                .Select(x => new ClassRoomModel() {
                    IdClassRoom = x.Key,
                    ClassRoom = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("ClassRoom"),
                    Students = x.Select(y => new StudentModel() { IdStudent = y.Field<int>("IdStudent")}).ToList()
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class StudentModel
    {
        public int IdStudent { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassRoomModel
    {
        public List<StudentModel> Students { get; set; }
        public int IdClassRoom { get; set; }
        public string ClassRoom { get; set; }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You can group-by more than one field

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` to load students from an SQL query, you don't need the interim `DataTable` step. You can simply load them using the reader:

```
Dictionary<int, ClassRoomModel> models = new Dictionary<int, ClassRoomModel>();
List<ClassRoomModel> classroomModels = new List<ClassRoomModel>();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ClassRoom, IdClassRoom, IdStudent FROM ClassroomStudentView", conn)) // whatever your real query is

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // this will return `true` until there aren't any results from the query
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // get the classroom id and check if we need to create a new model for it
        // (i.e. it doesn't currently exist in the dictionary)
        int classRoomId = (int)reader["IdClassRoom"];
        if (!(models.TryGetValue(classRoomId, out ClassRoomModel model)))
        {
            // read the classroom name and create the new model
            string classRoom = (string)reader["ClassRoom"];
            model = new ClassRoomModel() { IdClassRoom = classRoomId, ClassRoom = classRoom, Students = new List<StudentModel>() };
            // put it in the classrooms dictionary ("models")
            models[classRoomId] = model;
            // add the same in-memory object to the list for our final result
            classroomModels.Add(model);
        }

        // add the current student to the classroom model's students list
        int studentId = (int)reader["IdStudent"];
        model.Students.Add(new StudentModel() { IdStudent = studentId });
    }
}

// Now you have `classroomModels` populated with the grouped classroom objects.
```